# Finding the function f(t) from it's graph

Tags: functions

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

$$f(t) = (-2(t+1)+1.5) \times (u(t+1)-u(t)) + (t-0.5) \times (u(t)-u(t-1)) + 0.5\cos(\pi t) \times (u(t-1)-u(t-3))$$

I found the majority of this function, but I'm not sure how to account for the edges (the vertical lines at \$t=-1\$ and \$t = 3\$).

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: Because I haven't accounted for the vertical lines at t=-1 and t=3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general math problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heaviside function has a discontinuity at \$t = 0\$, so your terms that look like
$$
u(t) - u(t + 1)
$$
already deal with the discontinuities at \$t = -1, 3\$. I've added a picture of the first term to show the jump at \$-1\$.

[image]

Note that some plotting software doesn't show these discontinuities as vertical lines. This makes sense, because the function can only have one value for any given \$t\$ - a vertical line doesn't pass the vertical line test.

Comment: +1 for "a vertical line doesn't pass the vertical line test",